# Does It Make Sense to Write Unit Tests for Code Completely Covered by a Spec?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, specifications

We use both (executable) specs and unit tests in some of our financial software. The specs cover business behavior, the unit tests cover code. We use other testing methods as well, such as automated integration tests, etc., but that's not what I'm asking about here.

Sometimes I'll be writing code which, by its very nature, I know is -- and always will be -- completely covered by a spec, because it is core business functionality. An example would be rounding rules.

In these times I'm conflicted between wanting to write unit tests anyway (because of a feeling that the business requirements could change, even when they seem, as in the case above, like something which will be an issue forever) and feeling like I'm wasting time writing "redundant" unit tests.

Has anyone found good rules of thumb for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...Speed isn't an issue in this case. The executable specs and the unit tests are both quite fast, and in fact run as one unit; the specs are wrapped in unit tests so that they all run together...

As far as I understand above means that having unit tests in addition to *executable specs* won't help in discovering bugs faster, correct?

Well given that, the only *rule of thumb* that comes to mind is to look at it from the perspective of some *future maintainer*. You know, the guy who doesn't know you, the guy who doesn't share your current knowledge - some guy who just got your code to deal with. How to make life easier for that guy?

Let's see...

- if I choose to write *duplicate* unit tests, this may confuse my imaginary future-maintainer. "Why oh why did this idiot wrote duplicate tests? What was he thinking about?"
- if I decide to simply *skip* unit tests, this may be confusing, too. "Oh this isn't covered by unit tests why could that be? Is it because it's already covered by some executable spec or because someone just forgot to write a unit test here?"

In both cases the problem seems to be that I failed to reveal my intent. I failed to express the reasons why I did it one or another way. Solution is, respectively, to find a way to **express my intent**. For this, I'd use an annotation or self-explaining code like

```
  assertTrue("missing unit test", BusinessKnowledge.okToRelyOnSpecTests());
  // make okToRelyOnSpecTests return false if you find it to be... well, false
```

Whether to use annotation or code is probably a matter of personal preference. Or a matter of team habits/practices. Just be consistent and do not mix - following the same rule of thumb "not to confuse future maintainer".

We don't want this guy to spend sleepless nights trying to figure hidden reasons *why some parts are covered by annotations while other are served by code* do we? :)

Answer (score 1):

Are your specs executable? If not, you need automated tests (whether we're talking about unit tests or acceptance tests).

Comment: Yes, the specs are executable, and we have automated integration tests as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask instead:
"Does it make sense to write unit tests for code *not* completely covered by a spec?"

If you don't know how it should work, can you write tests for it?

Yes, you probably can, but then you will in effect add to the specifications by writing the tests.

It's not really a question about specifications vs. tests, rather that the tests confirm that the code works according the specifications.

Even if the specifications seems to cover everything, you will most likely find while writing tests that there are still some cases that are not covered. In that sense you not only test the code, but also the specifications.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main goals of unit testing is to find problems *fast*.  If your integration tests and/or executable specs take any significant time to run (which most do), I'm guessing that you don't run them nearly as often as your unit tests.  In such a case, it might be quite worthwhile to create unit tests even though there are more "expensive" tests that verify similar behaviour.

Comment: Speed isn't an issue in this case. The executable specs and the unit tests are both quite fast, and in fact run as one unit; the specs are wrapped in unit tests so that they all run together. Integration tests take longer, but that's not what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main functions of testing - unit testing in particular but not exclusively - is to establish that the code actually meets the spec. If you don't test, how do you establish that the produced system does what is required?  Testing is never wasted, so long as it is not a duplicate of already done, ineffective, previous tests. It is also possible to develop target focus - oh I know that code has been/will be tested - I don't need to bother. It's the old and often fatuous management speak - assume makes an ass of u and me.

**EDIT**
The additional information that specs are wrapped in unit tests; that your specs are executable; and you have automated integration testing; does imply that in some circumstances the writing of additional unit tests will be redundant. Based on your example, if your unit is not coding the rounding rules, but only using them defined elsewhere, then I would have thought it acceptable to omit any new unit test. In the case that you are coding the business rule, I would be inclined to reference the unit test that wraps the appropriate spec from your unit - either as a "null" test; or more usefully as a call to the spec unit test (if this is feasible) from your unit test.